# How to vertically align a text along with a double sized icon font icon in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have the following template

```
<td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200 text-sm leading-5 text-black-500">
    <i class="las la-circle-notch text-3xl"></i>
    <span>Provisioning</span>
</td>
```

now the template gets rendered as follows

[image: Imgur]

As you can see the text `Provisioning` is out of alignment. How to fix this?

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ppshobi/pen/poyvxpb)**

I am using [line awesome fonts](https://icons8.com/line-awesome), similar to font-awesome

Comment: Can I make a codepen out of your code?

Comment: because the content is inside a table cell, you can probably just add `vertical-align: middle;` to the table cells styles. Here it is in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/vertical-align)

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with code pen

Comment: https://codepen.io/ppshobi/pen/poyvxpb

Comment: @zgood, Actually I tried it before, but then the icon becomes slightly off aligned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [`align-middle`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/vertical-align/) for your icon. It works even regardless of being inside a `div` or `td`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/line-awesome/1.3.0/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.6.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200 text-sm leading-5 text-black-500">
    <i class="las la-circle-notch text-3xl align-middle"></i>
    <span>Provisioning</span>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Because you want a custom solution for the bigger icon and you want all the 3 texts to be aligned. You can add a custom class and adjust the margin/padding of the text of the provision icon. Note that I also corrected the 3rd table row markup because there were two classes used.

```css
.align-icon-middle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.align-icon-middle span {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/line-awesome/1.3.0/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.6.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="rounded bg-white border border-gray-300">
  <thead class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <th>IP Address</th>
      <th>Provision Status</th>
      <th>Connection</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="bg-white text-center">
    <tr>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200 text-sm leading-5 text-center">162.243.160.162</td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200 text-sm align-icon-middle  leading-5 text-center align-icon-middle">
        <i class="las la-circle-notch text-2xl animate-spin"></i>
        <span>Provisioning</span>
      </td>
      <td class="flex-col px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200 text-sm leading-5 text-center "">
        <div>
          <i class="las la-square text-green-500"></i> Active
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The align-middle I have tried it before. But then the text/icon is still off a little. Or its me confused by looking at it?. Please check my codepen, I have updated it with a 5xl icon, I feel the text and icon compared to the other `td` columns in table are off by little pixels. :|

Comment: Actually in 2xl icons its more evident. https://share.getcloudapp.com/7KuLyevP

Comment: @Shobi maybe check the line-height of the icon and the span

Comment: @Shobi I can only think of a custom solution for now. Check the edit.

Comment: Wow. Thats cool. Thank you. If I remember correctly, Like @zgood said, there is some trick involved with line height. But I don't know what to look for. But Thank you for your answer. It works